# How to add one entity reference field that can reference either a node or a user?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm looking to create an entity reference field that can reference either nodes from a specific bundle, or users. Is their a way to do this either with a module , or programmatical,y?

Comment: You don't. Entityreference doesn't support it, and it's a sign of a bad architecture. Have two separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this with the Entity reference module.  Look at its code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_info().
 */
function entityreference_field_info() {
  $field_info['entityreference'] = array(
    'label' => t('Entity Reference'),
    'description' => t('This field reference another entity.'),
    'settings' => array(
      // Default to the core target entity type node.
      'target_type' => 'node',
      // The handler for this field.
      'handler' => 'base',
      // The handler settings.
      'handler_settings' => array(),
    ),
    'instance_settings' => array(),
    'default_widget' => 'entityreference_autocomplete',
    'default_formatter' => 'entityreference_label',
    'property_callbacks' => array('entityreference_field_property_callback'),
  );
  return $field_info;
}
```

I suggest you try a work-around.  For example, you could create a content type that includes two entity-reference fields, one of type Node and one of type User.  Maybe, for convenience, include a boolean or integer field indicating which of the two to use.  Then use references to your new content type where you want to use node-or-user entity references.

Alternatively, you could use the Field collection module, which works the same way, creating node types to handle collections of fields:  https://drupal.org/project/field_collection.

Answer (score 0):

For D8 this is now possible with the Dynamic Entity Reference field:

https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference